# How to access the response for a form_tag in rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I have a form which submits number of info in Db.This form is on a modal popup. On click of submit tag, a new modal popup is displayed which has two buttons on click they show the data which the form has submitted.
Now the problem is till when the controller call is finished, these buttons do nothing on click.
So i want to add a spinner on the form popup on click of the submit button. and when the response comes true/ successful it shows the next popup.

my code looks like this:

```
form:

= form_tag("/system/upload_form", method: 'post', enctype:   'multipart/form-data', remote: true) do
    ...
    ...
    =submit_tag("Submit",id: "submit_button", class: 'btn btn-default')  



controller:

sys = @system.update!(system_params)
respond_to do |format|
  format.js
  format.json { render :json => sys }

js:

$("#submit_button").click(function() {
    $('#modal_define_system').modal('hide'); // current popup
    $('#next-page').modal('show'); // next popup
});
```

Now i want to know how and where to access the json object or sys value returned from the controller.

I tried:
Adding a class to the form and then

```
$('.form_class').bind('ajax:success', function() {
   console.log(sys);
});
```

But could not succeed.Plese help and advise. Comment if i need to add some more code or explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You are using form `form_tag` with `remote true`, which send the ajax request with js format not the json. If you render json response in js block instead of json in the controller like below, it should work.

```
  respond_to do |format|
     format.js { render :json => sys } #this will be rendered 
     format.json { render :json => sys } #this won't
   end
```

Alternately you can render javascript file like this

```
$('#results_div').html("<%= @system.try(:title) %>")
```

in `update.js.erb`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds silly, but how do i access sys in my update.js.erb ?

Comment: You can use instance variable `@system` instead as you have already defined it.

Answer (score 1):

extending maximus' code, you can use ajax to submit the form which can
      be more easy for you as per your case. You can try

```
     $("#theForm").ajaxSubmit({url: '/system/upload_form', 
     type: 'post'}).success(function(data){
     $('#newModalContainer').html(data);
     });
```

and in your controller, render html of your modal you want to show with your submitted values which can be passed in instance variables.
something like

```
     def upload_form
      #your logic
      render :partial => 'new_modal_to_show'
     end
```

this is a generic structure and you can change it to your relevant values. Hope it helps :-)

Comment: this means i need to change my current implementation ?? where i have added controller link in the form tag

Comment: for your ease if you can ... ajaxSubmit your form with submit button click. And get the response on the same page and show it in the partial. 
You can also go for solution @maximus porvided by responding in js format and set your variables there.